# How can i resolve this compile time error

Tags: compiler-errors, compile-time

ant -f "C:\Users\CD Fever\Documents\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main" -Dnb.internal.action.name=build jar
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\CD Fever\Documents\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\CD Fever\Documents\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-jar.properties
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)